# How do you solve this diff. eq $x(y'(x))^2-2y(x)y'(x)+2y(x)+x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this differential equation:

$$x(y'(x))^2-2y(x)y'(x)+2y(x)+x=0$$

I have tried substituting $y'=u$ but it doesn't seem to work. How do I solve differential equations that have a nonlinear derivative term?

Comment: You could try letting $y(x)=xu(x)$ for some $u(x)$. I think that would allow you to simplify it nicely.

Comment: @Bihc I doubt this allows to get rid of the nonlinearity with respect to $y'$ or $u'$.

Comment: While it easy to guess one family of solutions ($y(x) = x^2/p+x+p/2 $ for a parameter $p$), the rigorous proof that there are no other solutions does not seem to be as easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution suggested by Bihc in his comment seems to work.

For $y=xu \rightarrow y'=u+xu'$ the equation becomes:

$$
2xu+x(xu'+u)^2-2xu(xu'+u)+x=0
$$
$$
x(x^2u'^2-u^2+2u+1)=0
$$
and, for $x\ne 0$ we can find $u'$:
$$
u'=\dfrac{\pm \sqrt{u^2-2u-1}}{|x|}
$$
so we have two separable equations that , I suppose, you can solve.

Comment: That seems like a good way to go. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Since that is a quadratic equation in y', the first thing I would do is use the quadratic formula to solve for y':

$y'= \frac{2y\pm\sqrt{4y^2- 4x^2}}{2}= y\pm \sqrt{y^2- x^2}$

Comment: I don't see how that makes nonlinearity go away. Am I not just left with the same problem of not being able to solve the nonlinear $\sqrt{y^2-x^2}$ term?